# Rephrasing a sentence with negation and "except"

Tags: negation, multiple-negation, if

> I don't look as if I have done anything except study in the last three years.

I guess its meaning is two fold

1. In fact, there is only one thing that have been done which is "study in the last three years."
2. I wish I had done something other than study

Does the original sentense have the same meaning as the following two sentences?

> a. I (do) look as if I have done nothing except study in the last three years.
>
> b. I (do) look as if I have not done anything except study in the last three years.

I thought these are about double negation.

Answer (score -2):

Both of OP's alternative phrasing are syntactically valid, and mean the same as the original, but neither of them are particularly idiomatic. Especially not with ***do*** (except in some bizarre context refuting someone who just claimed you ***didn't*** look like that).

Personally, I'd say the *exact* form of the cited original isn't particularly idiomatic anyway. I'd normally expect another contraction and ***for*** rather than ***in...***

> *I don't look as if **I've** done anything except study **for** the last three years.*